# How to wrap each word of an element in a span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("div.date")
    .contents()
    .filter(
        function(){
            return this.nodeType != 1; 
        })
    .wrap("<span/>");
```

I am new and thought that code would have done the trick, but it wraps everything in the `<span>` like so:

`<div class='date'><span>`Dec 22, 2011`</span></div>`

It is supposed to look like this:

```
<div class='date'>
  <span>Dec</span>
  <span>22,</span>
  <span>2011</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to look into the [Lettering](http://letteringjs.com/) plugin.

Comment: Try to improve your question by giving an example of what you want. A better question name seems to be 'How to wrap **each word** of an element in a span tag?'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's gonna be a little more complicated than that. You're gonna have to find out all the words and re-append them to your element, wrapped in a span.

```
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $("p").append($("<span>").text(v));
});
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/VYfCh/)

Answer (score 32):

You don't *need* jQuery for this simple task. `String.prototype.replace` and regex should do the trick.

I just made some simple utility functions, that wraps letters, words and lines:

```
/**
 * Wraps a string around each character/letter
 *
 * @param {string} str The string to transform
 * @param {string} tmpl Template that gets interpolated
 * @returns {string} The given input as splitted by chars/letters
 */
function wrapChars(str, tmpl) {
  return str.replace(/\w/g, tmpl || "<span>$&</span>");
}

/**
 * Wraps a string around each word
 *
 * @param {string} str The string to transform
 * @param {string} tmpl Template that gets interpolated
 * @returns {string} The given input splitted by words
 */
function wrapWords(str, tmpl) {
  return str.replace(/\w+/g, tmpl || "<span>$&</span>");
}

/**
 * Wraps a string around each line
 *
 * @param {string} str The string to transform
 * @param {string} tmpl Template that gets interpolated
 * @returns {string} The given input splitted by lines
 */
function wrapLines(str, tmpl) {
  return str.replace(/.+$/gm, tmpl || "<span>$&</span>");
}
```

The usage is pretty simple. Just pass in the string to wrap as first argument. If you need custom markup, pass it in as the second argument, while `$&` is replaced by each char/word/line.

```
var str = "Foo isn't equal\nto bar.";
wrapChars(str); // => "<span>F</span><span>o</span><span>o</span> <span>i</span><span>s</span><span>n</span>'<span>t</span> <span>e</span><span>q</span><span>u</span><span>a</span><span>l</span> <span>t</span><span>o</span> <span>b</span><span>a</span><span>r</span>."
wrapWords(str); // => "<span>Foo</span> <span>isn</span>'<span>t</span> <span>equal</span> <span>to</span> <span>bar</span>."
wrapLines(str); // => "<span>Foo isn't equal</span> <span>to bar.</span>"
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, why does it wrap `isn't` as 2 different words?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson That's because `\w` **matches any word** character (alphanumeric & underscore), and `'` is in fact not a word ;) You could use `\S` instead, which **matches any character** that is **not a whitespace** character (spaces, tabs, line breaks etc). http://regexr.com/3d9p5

Comment: `'<span class="name">hello      world </span>'` not work, it cannot handle html properties well.

Answer (score 16):

If your element contents contains child elements (HTML) then the above solutions are not useful.

Here's a jsfiddle I've come up with that preserves HTML (elements and their attributes). The shortcoming of this small snippet is that if you have events binded to the element's contents then they will be lost since innerHTML is being reassigned to something else.

This code does not require any special libraries (like jQuery).

https://jsfiddle.net/4b5j0wjo/3/

```
var e = document.getElementById('words');
e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, '$1<span class="word">$2</span>');
```

Comment: This is good, but runs into problems when there are attributes like `class` on the child elements. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: @ClickerMonkey Thanks for the solution,  for a better and safe regex, check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380709/1966247

Comment: @user500665 did you fix it ?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to give each word a specific id, so, being a newbie, I studied the previously published answers code. Starting from Brad Christie's and Daniel Tonon's code I used .addClass to achieve this result:

```
    $('.mydiv').each(function(){ 
    var words = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
    var total = words.length;
    $(this).empty();
    for (index = 0; index < total; index ++){
      $(this).append($("<span /> ").addClass("myclass_" + index).text(words[index]));
      }
    })
```

which outputs:

```
    <div class="mydiv">
       <span class="myclass_0">bla</span>
       <span class="myclass_1">bla</span>
       <span class="myclass_2">bla</span>
    </div>
```

starting from:

```
    <div class="mydiv">bla bla bla</div>
```

It works perfectly for my needs. 
Maybe some expert programmers could tune up that better!

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of research I was able to safely do it by using the Negative lookbehind feature of Regex.

```
htmlStr.replace(/(?<!(<\/?[^>]*|&[^;]*))([^\s<]+)/g, '$1<span class="word">$2</span>')
```

Comment: ^ The only answer that works in all different cases ^

Comment: look behind is not supported by all browsers

Comment: look behind is not supported by react native

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<span><div class="date">Dec 22, 2011</div></span>
```

If so:

```
$('div.date').wrap('<span/>');
```

Or are you trying to get this:

```
<span>Dec</span> <span>22,</span> <span>2011</span>
```

Something like this shoul do the trick:

```
var dateInner = $('div.date');
var wraps = [];
$.each(dateInner.text().split(' '), function (key, value) {
  wraps.push = '<span>' + value + '</span>';
});

dateInner.html(wraps.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var $div = $('.words');
var divWords = $div.text().split(/\s+/);
$div.empty();
$.each(divWords, function(i,w){
  $('<span/>').text(w).appendTo($div);
});
```

Then

```
<div class="words">Why hello there, world!</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="words">
  <span>Why</span>
  <span>hello</span>
  <span>there,</span>
  <span>World!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, try [this](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js).

Specifically, you can find an example of how to split to words [here](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/wiki/Wrapping-words-with-lettering%28%27words%27%29)

Quote:

> Here's an example of the .lettering('words') method:
>
> ```
> <p class="word_split">Don't break my heart.</p>
>
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $(".word_split").lettering('words');
> });
> </script>
> ```
>
> Which will generate:
>
> ```
> <p class="word_split">
>   <span class="word1">Don't</span>
>   <span class="word2">break</span>
>   <span class="word3">my</span>
>   <span class="word4">heart.</span>
> </p>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just building on Xeon06 excellent answer.

I had to do this for a multiple of the same element on the same page.

```
    $('.element').each(function(){
        var words = $(this).text().split(" ");
        var total = words.length;
        $(this).empty();
        for (index = 0; index < total; index ++){
            $(this).append($("<span /> ").text(words[index]));
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple one-line answer if you want it for each word:

```
str.split(' ').replace(/\w+/g,"<span>$&</span>").join(' ');
```