# catch the words of a text html with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I 'm totally stuck ...
My level in javascript is not good enough to get me out of this problem
I tried using a regular expression javascript to catch the words of a text excluding html tags on a text in French
Here is my current regex

> ```
> ([^\r\n\t\f>< /]+(?!>))\b
> ```

The problem is that my accents are excluded and grabs my regex tags that it should not ( eg br html tag )

Here is a direct link to the test https://regex101.com/r/oT9uC1/10

my goal is to replace all word with span html tag
thank you all in advance for your help

Comment: [why, oh why with regex? It never stops...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I need to do a treatment on every word on render

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oT9uC1/11

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh great, there is just last things with words like Voilà in my example ( accent are not included ) . and it is possible to not get html tag ?

Comment: Regular expressions literally cannot reliably parse HTML tags. trincot has the correct answer: use the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML; it will always fail at some point.

Instead use the DOM API for this, which knows HTML better than anyone else:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = html;
var text = span.textContent;
var words = text.split(/\s+/);
console.log(words);
```

To wrap each word in a span tag, you can continue like this:

```
html = words.map(function (word) { 
    span.textContent = word;
    return '<span>' + span.textContent + '</span>';
});
```

Comment: my goal is to replace all word with span html tag in a second step , it is possible ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but if you have a question about how to wrap words in a tag, then that really is a different question. Still I added something in my answer. May I suggest you look also at earlier questions about that (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609170/how-to-wrap-each-word-of-an-element-in-a-span-tag)) or post a new question?

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you let me know?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd turn every word in an element into a span, I'd avoid regex, since DOM tools are provided by default.

```
var elementWithWords = document.getElementById('myElementId');  //get a reference to your element
var words = elementWithWords.textContent.split(/\s/);  //split on whitespace to get individual words
elementWithWords.textContent= '';  //clear out the html of the element
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { //for each word, create a span and append it to the original element
  var word = words[i];
  var wordSpan = document.createElement('span');
  wordSpan.textContent = word;
  elementWithWords.appendChild(wordSpan);
}
```

EDIT:
You could probably use the first with some finangling, however, below should work and keep your formatting. Note, anytime you set the innerHTML of something, be aware that it potentially opens you up to Cross Site Scripting Attacks.

```
var elementWithWords = document.getElementById('myElementId');  //get a reference to your element
var words = elementWithWords.textContent.split(/\s/);  //split on whitespace to get individual words

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { //for each word, create a span and append it to the original element
  var word = words[i];
  elementWithWords.innerHTML = elementWithWords.innerHTML.replace(word, "<span>" + word + "</span>");
}
```

Comment: thx , but your code remove html tag and space / point etc of my html code